# Compare two EXCEL files to delete duplicate data using Powershell

Tags: excel, powershell

I have a excel sheet that has number of columns and rows i need to delete all columns except one and delete all rows except predefined one(have an other excel sheet with one column and data(in rows) that are need to be deleted.
I have done the first that is to delete all the columns except, but i was only able to do that with Column number and i want to do this with Header name i.e. "Product Name" as Column number may change with other sheets.
Also want to do the same with Rows so i can compare row data from my reference execl.xlsx file and delete the one that are same.

```
$file = "C:\TE.xlsx" # here goes the path and name of the excel file.
$ColumnsToKeep = 4 # Specify the column numbers to delete.
$excel = New-Object -comobject Excel.Application # Creating object of excel in powershell.
$excel.DisplayAlerts = $False
$excel.visible = $False


$workbook = $excel.Workbooks.Open($file)
$sheet = $workbook.Sheets.Item(1) # Referring to first sheet.


$maxColumns = $sheet.UsedRange.Columns.Count

$ColumnsToRemove = Compare-Object $ColumnsToKeep (1..$maxColumns) | Where-Object{$_.SideIndicator -eq "=>"} | Select-Object -ExpandProperty InputObject
0..($ColumnsToRemove.Count - 1) | %{$ColumnsToRemove[$_] = $ColumnsToRemove[$_] - $_}
$ColumnsToRemove  | ForEach-Object{
[void]$sheet.Cells.Item(1,$_).EntireColumn.Delete()
}


$workbook.SaveAs("C:\data1.XLSX")


$workbook.Close($true)
$excel.Quit()
[void][System.Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($excel)
Remove-Variable excel
```

Comment: Do I understand it correctly that you want to delete all columns except one and all rows except one? This would imply that only a single cell is left.

Comment: No i want all columns deleted except one thats right, and the above code does that but it uses column number (i used 4 and save 4th columns in new file), but i want to do the same using column title. the above code is new file that has only one column that i want to keep starting with column title("product" ) i want to use "product" instead of column number(4). as may be in other sheets column number changes i have 1000 plus sheets.

Comment: The other thing is row. So each columns may have 40 to 300 rows  out of which 30+ will be same in all sheets and i want delete those common rows and keep unique only

Comment: @SyedAsadHaider - is this something that must be done with excel - using excel-specific file types? if not, then exporting to CSV and using the builtin CSV cmdlets seems likely to be far easier.

Comment: Yeah i can download files in CSV formate as well but i am new to powershell do not have any experience with CSV cmdlets

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Provided all your columns have headers in the first row, you can use this:

```
$file = "C:\TE.xlsx"
$columnToKeep = 'product'

$excel = New-Object -ComObject Excel.Application
$excel.DisplayAlerts = $false
$excel.Visible = $false

$workbook = $excel.Workbooks.Open($file)
$sheet    = $workbook.Worksheets.Item(1)

$maxColumns = $sheet.UsedRange.Columns.Count

# remove all columns except the one with header named $columnToKeep
for ($col = 1; $col -le $maxColumns; $col++) {
    if ($sheet.Cells.Item(1, $col).Value() -ne $columnToKeep) { 
        [void]$sheet.Columns($col).EntireColumn.Delete()
    }
}

$workbook.SaveAs("C:\data1.XLSX")
$workbook.Close($true)
$excel.Quit()

## clean-up used Com objects
$null = [System.Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($sheet)
$null = [System.Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($workbook)
$null = [System.Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($excel)
[System.GC]::Collect()
[System.GC]::WaitForPendingFinalizers()
```